# Finding the minimum number $m$ so that the inequality $|5x+11y+17z|≤m(|x|+|y|+|z|)$ is true

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to solve the following problem, but really have no idea where to start.

Find the minimum number $m ∈ R$ so that the inequality

$|5x+11y+17z|≤m(|x|+|y|+|z|)$

is true for every $x, y$ and $z$, with $x, y, z ∈ R$ and $x+y+z=0$

Answer (score 7):

Since $x+y+z=0$ by assumption, we have $$5x+11y+17z=(5x+11y+17z)-11(x+y+z)=-6x+6z.$$ Therefore
$$ |5x+11y+17z|=|-6x+6z|\le 6|x|+6|z|\le 6(|x|+|y|+|z|).$$
This shows that $m\le 6$.

On the other hand, if $y=0$, then $x=-z$, and the condition becomes
$$ |12z|\le  2m|z| \quad \forall z\in \mathbb{R}.$$

Therefore $m\ge 6$, and thus $m=6$.

Comment: Why we have m<=6 ?

Comment: Because the line above that shows that if you replace $m$ with $6$ in the condition, then the condition is satisfied. Therefore the minimum $m$ for which the condition is satisfied must be smaller or equal than 6.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Why 6|x|+6|z|≤6(|x|+|y|+|z|) shows that m≤6? Why did you put 6 instead of m?

Comment: @Futurballa What I prove in the first part of the answer is that, for any $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x+y+z=0$, one has $|5x+11y+17z|\le 6(|x|+|y|+|z|)$. Therefore 6 is a number with the property you are requiring. Since you want $m$ to be the smallest number satisfying such property, you have $m\le 6$.